# Traefik Reverse Proxy Ubooquity failure

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

I've been scratching my head over this one for a while now. Just exploring docker and web dev.

Setting up a local network only web domain. I want to be able to access all my services by name.home  (plex.home, ebook.home, etc)

I've hit a wall with ubooquity. When I enter the url `http://ebook.home:2203/ubooquity/admin` everything is great, the page loads perfectly. When I enter `ebook.home`, it has trouble loading all the elements and looks like just the html is showing up.

This is my compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  ubooquity:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/ubooquity
    networks:
      - traefik-public
      - ubooquity
    ports:
      - 2202:2202
      - 2203:2203
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"
        #- "traefik.http.services.ubooquity.loadbalancer.server.port=888" # required by swarm but not used.        
        - "traefik.http.routers.ubooquity.entrypoints=web"
        - "traefik.http.routers.ubooquity.rule=Host(`ebook.home`)"
        #- "traefik.http.routers.ubooquity.rule=Host(`ebook.home`) && PathPrefix(`/admin`)"
        #- "traefik.port=2202"
        
        - "traefik.http.services.ubooquity.loadbalancer.server.port=2203"
        
        #redirect base URL to url/admin
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.ubooquity-addprefix.addprefix.prefix=/ubooquity/admin"
        #attach the middleware to the router
        - "traefik.http.routers.ubooquity.middlewares=ubooquity-addprefix@docker"        
networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
  ubooquity:
     external: true
```

What is happening here and how do i correct the issue?
Thanks!

edit: Traefik config

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.3.4
    command:
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.network=traefik-public"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.ubooquity-admin.address=:2203"
      - "--providers.docker"
      - "--api.insecure" # Don't do that in production
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=888" # required by swarm but not used.
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.home`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=web"
        #- "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=letsencryptresolver"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.service=api@internal"
        #- "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
        #- "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$apr1$$8EVjn/nj$$GiLUZqcbueTFeD23SuB6x0"
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager

networks:
  traefik-public:
    external: true
    attachable: true
```

curl output

```
:~$ curl -v ebook.home
*   Trying 192.xxx.x.xx:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to ebook.home (192.xxx.x.xxx) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ebook.home
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
```

Edit#2:
Looks like my reverse proxy is working properly, this may be a Ubooquity issue. When opening the console on the failed page it see multiple errors relating to css files not loading.

`The stylesheet http://ebook.home/ubooquity/admin-res/roboto.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.`

Still digging!

Comment: in `preferences.json` you can set the reverseProxyPrefix to empty

Answer (score 0):

can you share your traefik config ?

What is the config for web entrypoint ? Have you specified 2203 port ?
According to [treafik doc](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/#configuration-examples), it should looks like

```
## Static configuration
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":2203"
```

PI: You don't need to expose 2203 port in your docker file as your ubooquity container is in the same network as traefik

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to docker/web dev in general and I find it very difficult to find explanations online.

My most relevant experience has been with virtualized VMs.

My understanding of the entrypoints was all traffic goes to them, then traefik redirects it to the container after that? so my request goes to `ebook.home:80` then traefik middleware should forward through the loadbalancer to `ebook.home:2203` and my add prefix suffixes the `/ubooquity/admin`